# Unable to install Babel locally in a project

Tags: node.js, babeljs, babel-cli

I'm following the steps from here https://babeljs.io/setup#installation.

I create a package.json file and then run

```
npm install --save-dev babel-cli
```

I get the error:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 17.7.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-- 
save-dev" "babel-cli"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! file /Users/name/Desktop/Graphs/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! No data, empty input at 1:1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! ^
npm ERR! File: /Users/name/Desktop/Graphs/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. 
JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/name/Desktop/Graphs/npm-debug.log
```

I've tried

```
npm cache clear
```

and

```
npm update
```

But it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Post your package.json, the error says your package.json cannot be parsed

Comment: It seams that something is wrong with your package.json

Comment: It's blank. I'm a newbie and thought that it would be populated when I installed babel-cli...

Is there a specific template I should use to create some info about the project?

Comment: Sorry, I added
    {}
in my package.json and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong in your `package.json`. Rather than start with a blank file, you should run

`npm init`

to generate a template for a `package.json` file.

If you don't want to answer all of the questions to customize the template, run

`npm init -y`

to generate a blank, default template.